# How to store the Trie data structure created in a database and implement to large system in production?

Tags: java, database, elasticsearch, data-structures, trie

Let's assume I have written code for creating the Trie data structure, but now I want to store the data structure in some sort of database so, if I rerun my application don't have to create a whole data structure again and storing data structure in memory for large data set is quite expensive.
How can we store Trie in databases like elastic and directly fetch it from there?

Comment: If you visualize a Trie, it is nothing but a kind of Tree. And, a tree is a graph without cycles. So, you need something which will help you to store data/nodes and their relationships/links right? Then, it's time to explore `Graph Databases`. 

Also, there is a nested document concept in ElasticSearch, but I would recommend going with a database here instead of ES.